# Importing functions from script with argparse in Python

Tags: python, parsing, argparse

I have written script A in Python, that uses ArgumentParser and switches through argparse when it is ran from cmd line. Now, I need to write a second script, that uses functions from A, but has it's own parser for it's own inputs

in script A my argparse function:

```
def switches():
    filepath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='log-analyser')
    parser.add_argument('-ch', '--channels', help='desired number of output channels. 0 here will terminate the script.', default=2, type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--ranges', nargs='?', help='input the ranges limits. use square brackets format [a,b,c,....,n] to get a-b, b-c, c-d, (...) ranges. DONT USE SPACES! frames beyond the limits will not be checked.')
    parser.add_argument('-m', '--margins', nargs='?', help='input the margins for stated ranges. use square brackets format [x,y,z,...,xz] to get x for a-b, y for b-c etc. DONT USE SPACES! (r-1) margins needed. ')
    parser.add_argument('-log', '--logfilepath', default='log1', help='filename of input_logfile to process (logfile for pcmtool supported). could be whole path to input_logfile.')
    parser.add_argument('-pre', '--prefix', default='', help='output file prefix and name of folder for outputs. optional; if left empty, program will output files with input_logfile prefix (e.g. log1_errors_ch1.txt).')
    parser.add_argument('-outdir', '--outputpath', default=filepath, help='path for every output for this program. .py file dir by default.')
    parser.add_argument('--marginsfilename', default='margins.txt', help='name of margin file to process. optional; if file exists, program inputs ranges and margins from this file. if file doesnt exist, it will be created, but correct -r and -m data is required.')
return parser.parse_args()
```

and I need a couple other functions from this script, for example this one:

```
def convert_to_floatlist(string_input):
    out = string_input
    out = out.replace('[', '')
    out = out.replace(']', '')
    out = out.split(',')
for i in range (0, len(out)):
    out[i] = float(out[i])
return out
```

but, when in the second script i call

```
from log_analyser import convert_to_floatlist
```

all i get from script B is failed argument checking from script A

```
>> Please use -r & -m switches or specify correct marginfile directory. Program will now terminate.
```

is there a workaround for it? I don't need the switches() from A, but I need a couple other functions and I would like to argparse in B.

Comment: It seems like `log_analyser` doesn't use an `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard; you should put one in.

Comment: wow, thanks, it helped immediately!